# Prove that $a^x$ is continuous for a>0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Here is what I need to prove: Let $a>0$ be a positive real number.  Then the function $f: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x):=a^x$ is continuous.

We are not supposed to use logarithms.  Some of the hints given are:

1. For $a>0$, limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $x^{1/n}$ is $1$.
2. Try to use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: This partially depends on how you define $a^x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not partially, entirely!!

Comment: See the first answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762614/how-to-prove-continuity-of-ex

Comment: In the first hint, what is the relationship of $a$ and $x$?

Comment: "Entirely" would mean the proofs are entirely different if the definitions are different, and that you can't get different proofs for the same definition. :) @MathematicsStudent1122

Comment: Really, the problem is not deserving of answers until the defintion of $a^x$ is made clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} a^x = 1$ since $|a^y - a^x| = |a^x||a^{y-x}-1|.$

The construction of the exponential function generally proceeds by defining it first for rational exponents. Extension to irrational exponents  $x$ follows by taking $a^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}a^{r_n}$ where the rational sequence converges monotonically to $x$.  All that is needed here is the property that $a^x$ is monotone increasing with respect to $x$ if $a > 1$ and monotone decreasing if $0 < a < 1$.

For any number $x \in (-1,1)$ there exists an integer $N$ such that $-1/N < x < 1/N$.

Hence, if $a > 1$

$$a^{-1/N} < a^x < a^{1/N},$$

and the squeeze theorem shows that $a^x \to 1$.

If $0 < a < 1$, then the same argument applies to $1/a$.

Comment: Very thorough and at the same time very simple. +1